# Database System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, winforms

I'm trying to use database:

```
 SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\DB\LogiDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
            string query = "Select * from tbl_Login Where username = '" + textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() + "' and password = '" + textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower() + "'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, sqlcon);
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dtbl);
            if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
               //
            }
```

my files is:

```
dbo.Table.sql
LogiDB.mdf
LogiDB_log.ldf   
tbl_Login.sql
```

not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I press to button I got this with line `sda.Fill(dtbl);`:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid object name 'tbl_Login'.
```

Comment: Not the solution to this problem, but please pay attention to [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: 1. Your `Sqlconnection` did not point to the target database, find the correct sql connection string, the connection string has nothing to do with your database files. you could try to find one in visual studio(not OLE DB connection, remove `provider`); 2. you forgot to `open` the sql connection before you `execute` the query

Comment: Do not store passwords in the database for several reasons.

Comment: @Hans Hello, not sure what is a good way to create server  login for user password  desktop application

Comment: @LONG hello, it is automatically taken string  without private path for example

Comment: @nikoria The userid/password for the system access to the SQL can be stored encrypted in the client. A common technique for handling user password is to store a hash value of the password and not the password itself, If someone gets access to the database, they need to brute force to figure out each users password. Also extend the password with salt. Google this, there are lots of articles and better design for security rather than adding it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error says: `Invalid object name 'tbl_Login'`

This might mean:

- tbl_Login table doesn't exist in you database
- you are connecting to wrong database

Since you have tbl_Login.sql script, I guess it contains table definition. Therefore you would need to run script to create table in your LogiDB database.

[Here there is example how to connect to local database](http://nikgupta.net/2015/12/10/connect-localdb-from-management-studio/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code work perfectly,
You can try this and compare your code

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=AVREST\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
            cn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select loginID,loginPassword from logintavle where loginID='" + textBox1.Text + "'and loginPassword='" + textBox2.Text + "'", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            //sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            DataTable dataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dataset);
            if (dataset.Rows.Count > 0)
```